# Set multiple properties from a form selection to state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, state, code-duplication

**CODE DUPLICATION**

So I am trying to have an inital state object like: `{prop1: val1, prop2: val2}` and get seperate values from two `<selection>` fields.
I am having problems with getting each `event.target.value` on submit.
The only solution I came up with is splitting the original state into different objects, duplicate the handler functions and merge them on submit. But as you can see this is getting ugly pretty quick, I am sure that this could be optimized but I am getting nowhere with the unique event handlers.

```
const [firstSelection, setFirstSelection] = useState({color: 'green'})
const [secondSelection, setSecondSelection] = useState({time: 'evening'})

const handleFirstChange = e => setFirstSelection({ color: e.target.value })
const handleSecondChange = e => setSecondSelection({ time: e.target.value })

const getSelection = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log({...firstSelection, ...secondSelection})
}

const Form = () => {
    return (
        <form>
            <div className='selectWrapper'>
                <select name='color' value={firstSelection.color} onChange={handleFirstChange}>
                    <option value='red'>Red</option>
                    <option value='blue'>Blue</option>
                    <option value='yellow'>Yellow</option>
                    <option value='green'>Green</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div className='selectWrapper'>
                <select name='time' value={secondSelection.time} onChange={handleSecondChange}>
                    <option value='morning'>Morning</option>
                    <option value='evening'>Evening</option>
                    <option value='night'>Night</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <input type='submit' value='Submit' onClick={getSelection}/>
        </form>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
export default function Form() {
  const [selection, setSelection] = useState({ color: "red", time: "morning" });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setSelection({ ...selection, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  const getSelection = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(selection);
  };

  return (
    <form>
      <div className="selectWrapper">
        <select
          name="color"
          value={selection.color}
          onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
        >
          <option value="red">Red</option>
          <option value="blue">Blue</option>
          <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
          <option value="green">Green</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div className="selectWrapper">
        <select
          name="time"
          value={selection.time}
          onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
        >
          <option value="morning">Morning</option>
          <option value="evening">Evening</option>
          <option value="night">Night</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick={getSelection} />
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, "[e.target.name]: e.target.value" was unknown to me - this solves the problem

Answer (score 2):

You can try to create just one fuction to update state that use the `name`s of the `<select>`s tags as keys of the state object. And concentrate all the data into one state. I will call this single state as `formState`

```
const [formState, setFormState] = useState({color: 'green', time: 'evening'})

const handleInput = e => setFormState({
  ...formState, 
  [e.target.name]: e.target.value  
})

const getSelection = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(formState)
}

const Form = () => {
    return (
        <form>
            <div className='selectWrapper'>
                <select name='color' value={firstSelection.color} onChange={handleInput}>
                    <option value='red'>Red</option>
                    <option value='blue'>Blue</option>
                    <option value='yellow'>Yellow</option>
                    <option value='green'>Green</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div className='selectWrapper'>
                <select name='time' value={secondSelection.time} onChange={handleInput}>
                    <option value='morning'>Morning</option>
                    <option value='evening'>Evening</option>
                    <option value='night'>Night</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <input type='submit' value='Submit' onClick={getSelection}/>
        </form>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a reusable component for select and use object for selection value, retrieved by input name

```js
const CustomSelect = ({ name, options, value, onChange }) => {
  return (
    <div className="selectWrapper">
      <select name={name} value={value} onChange={onChange}>
        {options.map((option) => (
          <option value={option.value}>{option.label}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function Form() {
  const selectData = [
    {
      name: "color",
      options: [
        { label: "Red", value: "red" },
        { label: "Blue", value: "blue" },
        { label: "Yellow", value: "yellow" },
        { label: "Green", value: "green" }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "time",
      options: [
        { label: "Morning", value: "morning" },
        { label: "Evening", value: "evening" },
        { label: "Night", value: "night" }
      ]
    }
  ];
  const [selection, setSelection] = useState({
    color: "green",
    time: "evening"
  });

  const getSelection = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(selection);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form>
        {selectData.map((sd) => (
          <CustomSelect
            name={sd.name}
            options={sd.options}
            value={selection[sd.name]}
            onChange={(event) =>
              setSelection({
                ...selection,
                [event.target.name]: event.target.value
              })
            }
          />
        ))}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick={getSelection} />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Codesandbox demo

[image: Edit winter-leaf-4sqf7]

Comment: interesting solution, I will try this and hopefully learn the concept of this extra component creation!